# Should I use DocumentClient (CosmosDB) directly in a desktop client

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

It seems if I use a DocumentClient directly in a desktop app it is exposing a security issue relating to the api key used in constructing the Doucument Client.
There doesn't seem to be a way of securing the key. Bringing the key into the client could lead to a hacker having full control over the database. It appears to me that the only way is to put the DocumentClient behind a Web Api or cloud Function.

So am I correct in saying never use DocumentClient in the client if you can't secure access to the app?

Answer (score 3):

Having the DocumentClient directly accessible means that the customer has access to the key. You can utilize obfuscation to try to hide it but it's very easy to actually just monitor the traffic of the app and capture the key or even dump it as a string from the memory during runtime, when it's unencrypted. You could use resource tokens but again, this is too much of a risk.

What you really want is to have your desktop client talk to an API with it's own auth that will talk to CosmosDB itself.

Comment: The DocumentClient uses  HTTPS for requests so presumably you couldn't access it by earsdropping the network. But I beleive that a hacker can look at the process memory and grab the key like that.

Comment: @PaulStanley Since encryption on outgoing requests happens on the application layer you can easily catch it as plain text if you really want. Just make an API and you will be safe (assuming this api has proper auth)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already access to an Azure Subscription you could also store the api key in the [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/), which is a service specially for storing secrets.

So the client will request the api key from the key vault. To access the key vault you can authenticate against it using a client certificate as outlined [here](https://azurecto.com/azure-keyvault-authenticating-with-certificates-and-reading-secrets/).

Comment: Could you extract a key from a running app?

Comment: Since the key is only exposed on the wire using an https connection I'd say only if you gain access to the memory of the process and know what you are doing then I suppose you can. But therefor you have to have access to the physical computer itself first.

Comment: @PeterBons This wouldn't work since still need a key to access keyvault and this key can be retrieved easily. Even the certificate needs to either be installed on the machine it will be used on or have it's password hardcoded in the client when it is about to be used. Either way, this is a very unsafe way to access a database.